# C# HTTP Server with HTTPS Support

Tags: c#, ssl, https, webserver

I want to implement a simple HTTP Server / Listener in C# which supports HTTPs with a self signed certificate.

**Prerequisites**

- .NET Framework 4.6.1
- Console Application

I am using EmbedIO for the Web Server. I've also tried CeenHttpd and Microsofts HttpListener class.

**Creating the private / public key**

To create a private / public key which I want to use for my X509 certificate, I run the following command in my machine's Linux Subsystem (Ubuntu):

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:1024 -days 365 -nodes -x509 -keyout test.key -out test.cert
```

To convert (or pack it?) into a pfx-File, I run the following command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out test.pfx -inkey test.key -in test.cert
```

**Application**

This is my Console application's code:

```
using EmbedIO;
using EmbedIO.Actions;
using EmbedIO.Files;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace EmbedIoTest
{
    class Program
    {
        public static DirectoryInfo GetExecutingDirectory()
        {
            var location = new Uri(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
            return new FileInfo(location.AbsolutePath).Directory;
        }

        private static WebServer CreateWebServer(string url, int port)
        {
            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"XXX\test.pfx");

            var exePath = GetExecutingDirectory();

            var server = new WebServer(o => o
                    .WithMode(HttpListenerMode.EmbedIO)
                    .WithCertificate(certificate)
                    .WithAutoRegisterCertificate()
                    .WithUrlPrefix("https://*:" + port))

                // First, we will configure our web server by adding Modules.
                .WithStaticFolder("/", exePath.ToString(), true, m =>
                {
                    m.WithDirectoryLister(DirectoryLister.Html).WithoutDefaultDocument().WithContentCaching(false);
                })
                .WithModule(new ActionModule("/", HttpVerbs.Any, ctx => ctx.SendDataAsync(new { Message = "Error" }))); ;

            return server;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var url = "127.0.0.1";
            var port = 8080;

            if (args.Length > 0)
                url = args[0];

            using (var server = CreateWebServer(url, port))
            {
                server.RunAsync();
                Console.ReadKey(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the server as a normal user, I get an error that I need to run the application as administrator to import the certificate.

If I run it as administrator, I get the error:

> SSL Certificate add failed, Error: 1312 A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.

If I remove the line "WithAutoRegisterCertificate()" from the WebServer instance, the console applications starts. But when I call the endpoint via CURL or Postman, I get no response.

Postman outputs:

> Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

Curl outputs:

> curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to 127.0.0.1:8080

**Solution**

What I need is a simple HTTP Server which supports HTTPS. That's all. But it should run independend of IIS / Apache / nginx etc. Is there a simple way to implement this?

Comment: Do you find a solution for EmbedIO Webserver?